# How to access objects between two xaml pages in wp7?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, navigationservice

I'm working on a wp7 application which consists of two xaml pages.
Pages are **Page1** and **Page2**.
Page1 consists of a **slider** which has a range of values between **0** to **10**.
My program is,if I slide the slider to reach value = 10,it should navigate to Page2.
So far so good.
But when Page2 is loaded,I want my slider to set its value to **0**.
But when I press the "back" key on my windows phone,the Page2 navigates to Page1 & the slider has the value = **10** (which should be **0**).
I cannot do the coding of slider from Page2 because it cannot access it! 
How should I do it?

The program for Page1(MainPage) is

```
namespace ProgressBar
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (slider1.Value == 10)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case just reset the slider to 0 before navigating to your Page2 or when you navigateback (there is a event for this in the NavigationService).

To share information accross your application in the general case you can just use static-classes/fields or objects your parse around or just persit the settings/info on file. It's the same as with any other environment.

Comment: I tried to reset slider to 0 before navigating.What I did is outside the if() block,I set the value as slider1.value=0; but as I run the prohram,the slider doesn't move at all! now what should I do?

Comment: outside the if-block? You should do this before the NavigationService.Navigate call.

Comment: After the Navigation call works as well. A call to Navigate isn't the equivalent of a return statement, so all code in the same tree is still executed.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the Slider value to 0 in the [Page.OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

Comment: How do I do it? I've provided my code,please help me with the syntax & the coding as per your logic.